# replace \: in selector for document.querySelector

Tags: css, google-chrome, puppeteer, devtools

I use chrome devtools to get the css selector of an element and I get something like this:

```
"wrap > div.flex-grow.pt-20.md\:pt-4.md"
```

This string doesn't work in document.querySelector.

How can I edit the string to match the element and be a valid input for document.querySelector?

Answer (score 0):

use Javascript selector instead.
(write `"\\:"` instead of `"\:"`)